# Play speed of embedded video in Powerpoint

Tags: video, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013, embedded-video

I thought this would be an easy question to find an answer to but surprisingly I hit dead-ends when googling.

My issue is that I have embedded a video from my computer in Powerpoint (in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013) and I was hoping to run it faster than 1X speed. I cannot find any option to do so. Is this something that can be done?

If not the only option I can think of is to try to edit the actual video clip to be faster somehow (does anyone have any recommended free software?). I can then simply embed the sped-up video.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use this link:
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00712_Playing_movies_in_slow_or_fast_motion.htm

for the 'windows media player' object enable the 'developer' tab from powerpoint options - custom ribbons - tick the developer box.
Once developer tab is shown click on more options - select the 'windows media player'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Windows Movie Maker you can adjust the speed of the video in that as well. I would recommend using that instead if you are trying to edit videos for powerpoint.